# How can i use index_var value as index in a list in ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Hy I would like to exchange individual lines in several config files with ansible.
To do this, I generate temp files in which I prepare the new lines.
Now I would like to use an index_var variable as index in a list in Ansible.

the variable my_idx is not evaluated. there is no error but the expression seems to result in an empty string. if I temporarily exchange the variable for a valid index, e.g. 0 or 1, it works.

Does what I want to do with ansible work at all?

```
- name: Read temp file with color list
  slurp:
    src: /etc/{{item.name}}.tmp
  register: color_files
  with_items:
  - { name: 'blue', code: '#346eeb'}
  - { name: 'red', code: '#eb3434'}
  - { name: 'black', code: '#000000'}


- name: change config files
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /etc/{{ item.name }}.properties
    regexp: '^font.color='
    line: font.color={{color_files.results[my_idx].content | b64decode}}"
  with_items: 
    - { name: 'blue', code: '#346eeb'}
    - { name: 'red', code: '#eb3434'}
    - { name: 'black', code: '#000000'}
  loop_control:
    index_var: my_idx
```

This works:

```
- name: Count our Colors
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "{{ item }} with index {{ my_idx }}"
  with_items:
    - { name: 'blue', code: '#346eeb'}
    - { name: 'red', code: '#eb3434'}
    - { name: 'black', code: '#000000'}
  loop_control:
    index_var: my_idx
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the attribute *code*? It is not used. IIUC, the case is to transfer the *font.color* from *.tmp to *.properties files. [edit] your question and make it [mre]. Post minimal content of the files and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there a several different question here ...

---

> ***I would like to exchange individual lines in several config files with Ansible.***

Because of the currently given description I like to recommend to use [Templating (Jinja2)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_templating.html)
with the [`template` module – Template a file out to a target host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html).

---

> ***How can I use `index_var` value as index in a list in Ansible?***

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    LIST:
      - A
      - B
      - C
      - D
      - E
      - F

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ item }} with index {{ my_idx }}"
    loop: "{{ LIST }}"
    loop_control:
      index_var: my_idx

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ LIST[item] }}"
    loop: [1, 2, 3]
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****************
ok: [localhost] => (item=A) =>
  msg: A with index 0
ok: [localhost] => (item=B) =>
  msg: B with index 1
ok: [localhost] => (item=C) =>
  msg: C with index 2
ok: [localhost] => (item=D) =>
  msg: D with index 3
ok: [localhost] => (item=E) =>
  msg: E with index 4
ok: [localhost] => (item=F) =>
  msg: F with index 5

TASK [debug] *****************
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) =>
  msg: B
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) =>
  msg: C
ok: [localhost] => (item=3) =>
  msg: D
```

Therefore

```yaml
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ LIST[my_idx] }}"
    loop: "{{ LIST }}"
    loop_control:
      index_var: my_idx
```

with output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****************
ok: [localhost] => (item=A) =>
  msg: A
ok: [localhost] => (item=B) =>
  msg: B
ok: [localhost] => (item=C) =>
  msg: C
ok: [localhost] => (item=D) =>
  msg: D
ok: [localhost] => (item=E) =>
  msg: E
ok: [localhost] => (item=F) =>
  msg: F
```

But as one can see it would be unnecessary and implementing functionality which is already there just again.

**Documentation**

- [Tracking progress through a loop with `index_var`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#tracking-progress-through-a-loop-with-index-var)
- [Extended loop variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables)